# How to make window-key open terminal on raspberry pi?

Tags: linux, key-binding

I'm trying to get the window key on my keyboard to open the terminal of my Raspberry Pi. Is this still possible. Everything I've found on google thus far has been from 2012 or earlier.

What I've tried thus far is editing the following:

```
vim ~/.config/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml

<keybind key="Super_L">
    <action name="Execute">
        <execute>lxterminal</execute>
    </action>
</keybind>
```

This doesn't seem to work. Anyone know the mapping for the windows key?

Answer (score 3):

There is already a shortcut to open a terminal in LXDE: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>. But if you want to change that...

The [openbox wiki](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Bindings) says:

> **W** - Super key (Usually bound to the Windows key on keyboards which have one)

You are using `Super`. Replace that with `W`, e. g. `W-L`. Also:

> A key binding is specified as follows:

```
<keyboard>
  ...
  <keybind key="KEY-COMBINATION...">
    ...ACTIONS...
  </keybind>
  ...
</keyboard>
```

Have you made sure that your keybind is within the `<keyboard>` tag?

Alternatively, to make your life easier, you can use [obkey](https://code.google.com/p/obkey/).